# MongoDB FindAndUpdate with cost

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I want to modify a specific field in Mongo db, is it expensive even if the value to be modified is the same as the existing field?

Comment: i am not sure but i think if mongodb loads a document and sees that nothing is changed, it skips the write(keeping the old value), so in this case i think you just pay the load to memory.

Comment: Was that an autocorrect fail?

Comment: @Takis_ Thanks, Are you saying it's okay to update without considering whether it's changed or not?

Comment: @Joe No, not yet. But when I update my data, I try to add a code to see if it has been changed or not

Comment: I was referring to "Mongolia db", seemed like something autocorrect would do.  I agree with @Takis_ - an update that doesn't result in a change is the same as a read.  It will be exactly as OK as running the equivalent find operation.

Comment: I was answering your question about netjs repositories, and you deleted it, if you are still interested, restore the question